# Using numprint to round numbers within a single column in a table

Tags: tables, booktabs, numprint

I like to use `numprint` to format my tables with numerical values, as it improves readability and alignment. However, sometimes I want to use a different rounding setting for a particular column, and it gives me issues. Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,numprint}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \nprounddigits{9}%decimal places to print
        \centering
        \caption{Example MWE table with \texttt{numprint}}
        \begin{tabular}{cn{2}{9}n{2}{9}c}
        %\begin{tabular}{cn{2}{9}n{2}{9}n{2}{4}}
            \toprule
            label   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c_0$}   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c_1$}   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Offset} \\
            \midrule
            1   &   0.0312345678965644  &   14.19485626621957   &   0.0041 \\
            2   &   0.0398765432197208  &   14.46309465237807   &   -0.0033 \\
            3   &   0.0369384756293342  &   14.44623978976586   &   -0.0012 \\
            4   &   0.0359572496569465  &   14.45124808402672   &   -0.0123 \\
            5   &   0.0348962975438688  &   14.74567899523164   &   -0.1234 \\      
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The rightmost column in this case is not typeset through `numprint`, and the decimal points are not aligned. Activating the `numprint` for this column is fairly easy. Just need to switch the last `c` by `n{2}{4}` in the `\begin{tabular}{cn{2}{9}n{2}{9}c}` as presented in the commented line. But this will also print the same number of rounding digits as the other columns. I would like to print the last column with `\nprounddigits{4}` but I don't know if it's possible. I look at the documentation for the `numprint` package, on SE forums and Google in general, without success. Hence, I settle for the option displayed in the example of no `numprint` for the last column. Could somebody share some recommendations about this possibility? I mean, setting a rounding parameter for a single column.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest switching to [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)? It allows you to switch between the formatting and rounding of elements on a column-by-column basis:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{
  table-auto-round = true % Round numbers in S-columns
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Example MWE table with \texttt{siunitx}}
  \begin{tabular}{ 
    c % label
    S[table-format = 1.9] % c_0
    S[table-format = 2.9] % c_1
    S[table-format = 2.4] % Offset
  }
    \toprule
    label & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c_0$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Offset} \\
    \midrule
    1 & 0.0312345678965644 & 14.19485626621957 &  0.0041 \\
    2 & 0.0398765432197208 & 14.46309465237807 & -0.0033 \\
    3 & 0.0369384756293342 & 14.44623978976586 & -0.0012 \\
    4 & 0.0359572496569465 & 14.45124808402672 & -0.0123 \\
    5 & 0.0348962975438688 & 14.74567899523164 & -0.1234 \\      
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @werner. Good advice.